# "Typecast" XmlListModel to Listmodel

Tags: qml

I have a XmlListModel that fetches data from a webserver, which works great.

However, I want to use that in a CLComboBox (from the Colibri library).

If I set the parameter ListModel to my XmlListModel I get:

```
Non-existent attached object 
         ListModel:xmlModel13
```

But it does exists; since a ListView-object can use the very same model.

It seems to me that the CLComboBox only accepts a ListModel, so is there any way to transform a XmlListModel to a ListModel easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cast `QDeclarativeXmlListModel` to `QDeclarativeListModel` because they both direct descendants of `QListModelInterface`.

In my opinion Colibri should use a `QObject` (`variant` property) instead of `QDeclarativeListModel`. And listen for standard item-based-model signals e.g. I believe it could be fixed with some effort.

If you not willing to contribute to Colibri, I think @sabbour's answer is best option. Consider simple example:

```
XmlListModel {
    id: xmlModel
    source: "http://forumcinemas.lv/rus/xml/Events/"
    query: "/Events/Event"
    XmlRole { name: "label"; query: "Title/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "value"; query: "ID/number()"; isKey: true }
    onStatusChanged: {
        if (status == XmlListModel.Ready) {
            for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
                var item = get(i)
                list_model.append({label: item.label,
                                   value: item.value,
                                   selected: false})
            }
            // CLComboBox doesnt seem to listen for model updates
            combo_box.items = list_model
        }
    }
}

ListModel {
    id: list_model
}

CLComboBox {
    id: combo_box
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can populate the ListModel inside the CLComboBox using a loop.