# add data to a qml XmlDataModel

Tags: qt, qml

gi, i have a question about qml and the XmlDataModel.
i have a xml file where i have something like this:

```
<model>
  <item title="one" />
  <item title="two" />
</model>
```

and i have a listView which has this data:

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    dataModel: XmlDataModel {
        source: "data/model1.xml"
    }
}
```

now i dant to add some data to this model when i e.g. press a button. how to make this?

Comment: What model do you use? The `XmlListModel` is a read-only model (as stated in docs).

Comment: There is only one built-in `XmlListModel`, and it is read-only. However, you can use it to fetch data and fill a `ListModel` with that data. `ListModel` is mutable model. You can find an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774587/typecast-xmllistmodel-to-listmodel/10789466#10789466

Comment: post this as a answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlListModel` is a read-only model by design. However, you can use it to conveniently fetch data and fill with that data a `ListModel` which is mutable model. You can find an example [here](/questions/10774587/typecast-xmllistmodel-to-listmodel/10789466#10789466).